# Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.2 upgrade, Unit tests now fail with missing GORM methods

Tags: unit-testing, grails-2.0

I am in the middle of upgrading an app from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.2

So far, its been relatively painless and straight forward.

Until we started running the unit tests.

Under 1.3.7, all the tests passed.

Under 2.2, about half are now failing.  The tests haven't changed, they are still the old style mockDomain...

What is most concerning to me is that basic gorm features are missing on some of the domain classes.

Things like .list and .get

> Failure:  testList_NoMaxSpecified_10Shown(com.litle.bldvwr.StreamControllerTests)
>   |  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: >com.litle.bldvwr.Stream.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: list(), list(), list(), list(java.lang.Object), list(java.util.Map), >list(java.lang.Object)

and

> Failure: >testAddFailureOutputToHappyPathWithIntegrationFailure(com.litle.bldvwr.LogParserServiceTests)
>   |  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: >com.litle.bldvwr.Result.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: get(java.io.Serializable), get(java.lang.Object), >get(java.io.Serializable), getId(), grep(), grep(java.lang.Object)

The general pattern of for this type of failure is:

```
mockDomain(Phase, [new Phase(id:1, name: 'xxx')])       
mockDomain(Result, [new Result(id:1, phase: Phase.get(1), failureOutput:"")])          
logParserService.addFailureOutputTo(Result.get(1))
```

And it is that last get that is causing the no signature error.

While we intend to start using the new Unit Test functionality, I was hoping to avoid having to rewrite the 500+ current tests.

Thoughts, ideas?

-Clark

Answer (score 1):

Using the new `@Mock()` annotation in your test for the domain objects will inject all the expected mock GORM methods, and you can even just `save()` your domain objects instead of providing the list in `mockDomain()` call.

```
@Mock([Result, Nightly])
class MyTests {
  void testSomething() {
    def night = new Nightly( name:'nightly1')
    night.id=1
    night.save(validate: false)

    assert Nightly.get(1).name == 'nightly1'

    assert Result.count() == 0

    new Result(status: Constants.SUCCESS, type: Constants.INTEGRATION, 
      nightly: Nightly.get(1)).save(validate: false)

    assert Result.count() == 1
    assert Result.findByStatus(Constants.SUCCESS) != null // yay dynamic finders!

  }
}
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains

You'll have to update all your tests to the new ways, but it's *much* nicer that the old 1.3 ways.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what we found.

With 1.3, you could do:

```
  {
   mockDomain(Nightly, [new Nightly(id: 7)])
    mockDomain(Result, [
        new Result(status: Constants.SUCCESS, 
        type: Constants.INTEGRATION, nightly: Nightly.get(7))
    ])
    service.callSomething(results, Nightly.get(7))
    assert result==Nightly.get(7).property
```

And it would work just fine.  You whoul have a Mock domain object with and id of 7, and the get would work just fine.

Since then, something  changed, and you can no longer set the id has part of the create.

What you need to do is this:

```
night = new Nightly( name:'nightly1')
    night.id=1
    mockDomain(Nightly, [night])
    mockDomain(Result, [
        new Result(status: Constants.SUCCESS, type: Constants.INTEGRATION, nightly: Nightly.get(1))
    ])
```

and that mostly sets up the mocks correctly.

The issue we ran into next was that outside of the mockDomain call, Nightly.get() would not work.

So now we need to save the "mocked" domains in local variables in order to do post action comparison and checks.

Not a completely horrible solution, but less elegant than we were hoping for.

Comment: Having to explicitly assign the id is due to some fields no longer being bindable by default from the constructor map.